# 'MapControl' is not exported from 'react-leaflet' in react-leaflet V3.0.0

Tags: react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw, react-leaflet-v3

Trying to implement react-lealfet-draw with react-leaflet version 3.0.0.
it throws an error
/node_modules/react-leaflet-draw/dist/esm/EditControl.js
Attempted import error: 'MapControl' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'.

```js
import "./styles/leaflet.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css";
import "leaflet-draw";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-splitmap";

import {MapConatiner, TileLayer} from 'react-leaflet';
import {EditControl} from 'react-leaflet-draw';
```

is there any way to implement leaflet-draw features with react-leaflet V3.0.0 ?

Comment: react-leaflet-draw doesn't seem to be compatible with react-leaflet v3, hence the error.  You'll need to rebuild it yourself as a react-leaflet v3 component or try to find a similar plugin that is already compatible with v3.

Comment: I down grade the react-leaflet to V2.0 and loose the feature of Side By Side tiles. Is there nay way to have splitMap in react-leaflet V2.0

Comment: Wellll how are you implementing leaflet-splitmap *now*?  A quick search does not reveal any ready-made react-leaflet-splitmap components.  Are you building it yourself?  My general recommendation would be *not* to downgrade react-leaflet to v2, but rather make your own custom components for react-leaflet version 3, built on top of these existing vanilla leaflet plugins.  I don't really have time to do this myself for you in an answer, but that would be the cleanest and more future-proof way to go about this

Comment: I think it was replaced with LayersControl. You can read more [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-layers-control/)

Comment: @Semb hey, thank you I have already done it with the leaflet on it's own, react-leaflet is not that flexible

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround you can do.
You can use react-leaflet version, eg. 3.2.5, and you can add on your package.json react-leaflet-draw v0.19.5, but if you let this in this way, it will have conflits.
The solution is to add a "override" on the dependencies on react-leaflet-draw to use react-leaflet v^3.0.0 and ignore the v^2.0.0

```
"overrides": {
  "react-leaflet-draw": {
    "react-leaflet": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```